# How to start 'gz sim' from a yaml launch file?

Tags: ros, ros2, roslaunch, yaml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'd like to start 'gz sim' from my yaml launch-file, I read [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/374976/ros2-launch-gazebolaunchpy-from-my-own-launch-file/) that it's easy in python with the ExecuteProcess class.
But when I tried to use

```
  # gazebo world
  - ExecuteProcess:
      cmd:
```

I got the error `[ERROR] [launch]: Caught exception in launch (see debug for traceback): Caught exception when trying to load file of format [yml]: Unrecognized entity of the type: ExecuteProcess` when I launched the file with `ros2 launch my_file.yml`

I did not found either a doc that help translate from Python class to Yaml.

Linux version 5.19.0-40-generic, Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414845/how-to-start-%27gz-sim%27-from-a-yaml-launch-file-?/) by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2023-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If anyone is interested I succeed with this launch :

```
  # gazebo world
  - executable:
      cmd: gz sim -v 1 -r my_world.sdf
```

If anyone knows where to find the full doc of the yml launch file, I'm still interested

---

Originally posted by [SébastienL](https://answers.ros.org/users/146607/s%C3%A9bastienl/) with karma: 32 on 2023-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0